# Invalid zip while compressing with ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

I get invalid zip, when writting to file the following code:

```
public static byte[] zip(final Map<String, byte[]> mapReports) {

  try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> report : mapReports.entrySet()) {
      ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(report.getKey());
      zos.putNextEntry(entry);
      zos.write(report.getValue());
      zos.closeEntry();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception zipping files", e);
  }
}
```

The way I write it to file is:

```
    byte[] zip = zip(mapReports);
    File file = new File("demo.zip");

    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        os.write(zip);
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of a ByteArrayOutputStream, use a FileOutputStream, based on a second method argument of type File.  If you try to keep the entire thing in memory, your program will have degraded performance when you have a lot of data.  For very large amounts of data, the performance penalty will be brutal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `close()` or `finish()` the `ZipOutputStream` stream *before* calling `baos.toByteArray()`.

Since a `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't need to be closed, and/or since you can call `toByteArray()` even after it has been closed, I'd recommend you move it outside the `try` block:

```
public static byte[] zip(final Map<String, byte[]> mapReports) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> report : mapReports.entrySet()) {
      zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(report.getKey()));
      zos.write(report.getValue());
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception zipping files", e);
  }
  return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that I returned a value before closing the ZipOutputStream.
Should have been:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
    ....
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception zipping files", e);
  }
 return baos.toByteArray();
```